# How can I finish Battle for Whiterun?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm fairly certain that I've started the quest, However, before talking to Galmar Stone Fist, I went and did other things first. Now I've finally gone to the White Run Encampment near Whiterun, but Galmar Stone Fist isn't there to give me orders. The quest is marked completed in the journal.

Here is a screen shot of Galmar Stone Fist in Windhelm keep.

[image]

[image]

Have the troops have attacked Whiterun without me and failed? I mean I spent a lot of time travelling around first after the go ahead. However, I expected the game to wait for me.

Oh well, what should I do now? I am supposed to destroy some barricade somewhere?

---

**Update:** For some reason Whiterun is accessible again. I didn't do anything, just traveling around. Did I fail the quest? The Stormcloak encampment is gone. Is this a good thing? Looks like I didn't participate at the battle at all and the Stormcloak won anyway without me. It seems that something I did in Falkreath "completed" the quest. Ulric notices that I wasn't there.

Comment: Who is the current Jarl of Whiterun? If it's not Balgruuf, then you won.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are talking about the civil war quest. The barricade that you need to destroy is at the draw bridge in front of the gates outside whiterun. Simply hit it a few times to destroy it and get ready to fight.
Perhaps this will help.
http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Battle_for_Whiterun_(Stormcloaks)

This is an excellent site not only for skyrim, but for all Elder Scrolls games.

Comment: Galmar is supposed to tell me that. He's not on the camp however. So they finish the war without me.